# Is there any VS code extension for FreeBSD?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access, freebsd

I want to open a folder on a remote machine which runs `FreeBSD`. Is there any extension in VS code? Is there any alternate way to easily edit files on a remote machine?

Comment: just use the remote SSH extension, it works with all *nix OSes

Comment: @rioV8 , Tq , I tried with remote SSH extension , after entering password I will get ```could not establish connection to blablabla```  ,in terminal I will get ```Unsupported platform: FreeBSD``` error

Comment: can you run VSC on FreeBSD?, where do you enter password (not needed for SSH)? Have you created an issue at the remote extension

Comment: @rioV8 , In vs code first I added host name(ssh username@hostname) and added same in confi file . Then I clicked on connect , I selected Linux plantform and entered password of the remote system.Then it will show the same error as i explained above.

can you run VSC on freeBSd means , now I am editing remote system files using ``vim``.
Whether I need to create issuse at remote extension ,how can i do that.

Comment: if you need to type a password you are not using SSH, you create a key for a user and need to upload it to the remote, go to the repo if the extension and create an issue

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this? I'm hitting the same problem myself and getting nowhere.

Comment: No @BlairHippo.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/727. tl; dr: FreeBSD is not supported at this moment.